# Set automatic zip value for Hong Kong in WooCommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Hong Kong does not have zip codes. Woocommerce sets the mandatory zip field to no-validate when country is set to Hong Kong.

But I need an entry for the zip field also for Hong Kong. Because we have a shipping software that needs always a zip.

How can I set the zip field to 00000 every time when Hong Kong is selected?

Comment: show some your code so it'll be easier to help.

Comment: I have no code already. It is a woocommerce issue in functions.php

Comment: why don't you set the default value for zipcode pin to 00000 so that when a place with pincode is selected the value will automatically set to that place pincode and when place with no pincode like Hong Kong is selected the default value of 00000 goes for them.

Comment: in other countries I need the real zip code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with this little code snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_script', 10 );
function custom_checkout_script() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', '#billing_country', function() {
                var location = $('#billing_country option:selected').val();
                if( location == 'HK' ) {
                    $('input#billing_postcode').val('00000');
                } else if( location != 'HK' && $('input#billing_postcode').val() == '00000' ) {
                    $('input#billing_postcode').val('');
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.